# not able to differentiate true and false using filter

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I want true and false to be differentiated using filter() but it is initializing the value to true and false. I want true values to come one side and false value to be on another side which would be separated by line.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Helloworld extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        Hello World {this.props.title}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class Items extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      {this.props.items.map(item => <div> {item} </div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Books extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      books: ['book1', 'book2', 'book3']
    }
  }
  cliclMe(){
    alert("clicked")
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>Add books</div>
        <input/>
        <input type="submit" onClick ={()=> this.cliclMe()}/>
        {this.state.books.map(book => <div>{book}</div>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Todo extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      {this.props.tdo.filter( (item) => {item.done ='true'})}
      {this.props.tdo.map((iterator) =>  <div> {iterator.todo}  {iterator.done}</div>) }
      <hr/>
      {this.props.tdo.filter((item) => {item.done ='false'})}
      {this.props.tdo.map((iterator) =>  <div> {iterator.todo}  {iterator.done}</div>) } 
    </div>
    )
  }
}
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
            <Helloworld title="monday"/>
            <Items items={[1, 2, 3]}/>
            <Books/>
            <Todo tdo={[{todo: 'todo1', done:'true'}, {todo: 'todo2', done:'false'}, {todo: 'todo3', done:'true'}]}/>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[this is output im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An5Og.png)

but 1 want some thing like :

todo1 : true

### todo3: true

todo2: false;

Comment: In this: `.filter( (item) => {item.done ='true'})` there are 2 issues. **1.** You are not returning anything. **2.** It should be `==` or `===` instead of `=`. Single equalsTo means assignment. double/triple means comparison. So it should be `.filter( (item) => item.done === 'true')`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Todo extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      {this.props.tdo.filter( (item) => item.done =='true')}
      {this.props.tdo.map((iterator) =>  <div> {iterator.todo}  {iterator.done}</div>) }
      <hr/>
      {this.props.tdo.filter((item) => item.done =='false')}
      {this.props.tdo.map((iterator) =>  <div> {iterator.todo}  {iterator.done}</div>) } 
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You should use == instead of assignment

Comment: Note: An answer is incomplete without explanation. What did you change? Why did you change? Why was OP's code not working

Answer (score -1):

`item.done ='true'` or `item.done ='false'` is assigning the value , instead you need `item.done ==='true'` and `item.done ==='false'`

Comment: Changing assignment to comparison will not make any difference. Refer my comment under question. Also, apologies. was typing that comment hence there was a delay in responding here

Comment: @Rajesh my answer clearly mention the second point. Anyway I know, it is your old habit.

Comment: I don't see any return value remark in your answer. So even if you address second point, it will not solve the issue. Hence downvote. If you edit and add that part as well, I'll take back my vote as that would be a complete answer

Comment: Also, my apologies if my behavior bothers you. Hope you agree with my point of this being a partial answer.